Is adding "in my opinion" or "according to my view" a bad thing?
I had a rather surprising exchange with a user, the formulations of whom I found aggressive and provocative. I understand that they don't mean any harm, just have a certain style of expression, so I've tolerated it - we're all different individuals. However, it struck me that they didn't reciprocate and, in fact, made a point that my statements are interpreted negatively.
I tried to make sure to amend my comments with "according to my experience" and "my opinion leans towards" to cater to an easier consensus, expressing respect for other, different views.
While I feel that I was polite and clear (although not submissive nor agreeable), I can't shake off the sensation that my politeness somehow got lost in translation and that the intended dignity actually is easily taken as passive-aggressive opposite.
This is the other person's statement as a response to me.

My critiques on your main posts are neutral & helpful & anyway I said ... "in my opinion" etc are misdirecting equivocating noise. I stand behind what I claim. And I'm not interested in "kinder to receive" at SE, rather, neutral & helpful.

I had to look up equivocation and it says ambiguous language so as to conceal the truth or avoid committing oneself. How should I get across to someone that I'm firm in my stance while not discussing others' views in a way that's not (reasonably) subject to misdirecting equivocation? (Insecure people or those with poor experience may always misinterpret anything. However, this particular person seems to be adequate in his behavior and linguistically proficient.)
I need a safer way to express myself in those situations in English.

The block quote that's the core of this question is difficult to make sense of, since it references earlier material. Is it presented word-for-word? I.e. are the words "& anyway I said...", and the quote marks, part of the original post itself? Or are you interrupting your quote of yourself to add info?

I'm afraid I don't understand this question at all, but I could imagine a question that I think asks what you mean to ask: Is it: "If I say 'in my opinion' about things I think are absolutely true, then I open myself up to the response 'Well, that's just your opinion.' How can I assert absolute truths without implying that they're subjective, while still being polite?" If that's what you're driving at, please edit to make that clear, and maybe give more context and detail to the quote.

In case this is closed down. those two expressions are fine. No need for more.. I don't understand the paragraph you cite nor who wrote those words.

Adding "in my opinion" or "according to my view" to neutral language is being modest. And adding it after you call my baby ugly is passive-aggressive. But that's just my opinion in my view.


I see now that the block quote must have been the other person's words, not your own, if you had to look up "equivocating." Please edit to make that clearer. And 2) Hm... it's not the same thing at all, but it seems like the other person's point is something along the lines of "Weasel words". I.e. they were challenging you to remove the "in my opinion" and state your claims more boldly. I'm not sure that challenge is sound, or even fair, advice. And I notice that I just started that last sentence with "I'm not sure that," a similar phrase!


@AndyBonner Oh, that's the opposite of what I meant. If one tries to pass an absolute truth but disguise it behind in my opinion, then I feel it is a manipulative rhetoric. What I meant was that I state something that I firmly believe but without imposing the expectation on the receiver to fold (or even reconsider). As for the left out part, it seemed a bit rant'ish and I didn't want to convey a poor view of the speaker, so I cut that out as irrelevant to the linguistic aspect.

@YosefBaskin Thanks for the comments. Regrettably, I don't quite get the message in the first one. Is there a typo in there or am I simply too slow to grasp your point? Help me understand, please.

@YosefBaskin I would never call anybody's baby ugly. In fact, passing any negative remark on personal treaties, physical features, financial/social status etc. is plain mean and unnecessary. Pointing out flaws that one can't control is simply retarded, in my view. The discussion I had with the person in question was about a formulation of a question about programming. No babies were involved.   :)

@AndyBonner I clarified the quotation, as suggested. As for the weisel words, I believe you're about right. I found that person's tone aggressive and "wolf'y" (if you're familiar with the concept of giraffe language). In fact, the subject was a matter of taste so I felt that stating facts was pointless - there's no contradiction in you fancying vanilla and me preferring banana. Assuming best intentions of theirs, I though, maybe, I can make my statement even more clear so that they won't need to interpret it as weasel'ish. (I want to presume that the person isn't a simple jack-ass.)

The question can be boiled down to: "Is it ever a bad idea to use phrases that emphasize subjectivity, like 'in my opinion'? Does it ever impede clear communication? Can it ever cause my tone to be misunderstood?"
First, let's acknowledge the value of using statements like these. Saying things like "in my opinion," "it seems to me that," or "in my experience" turn objective statements into subjective ones. This can be crucial to civil dialogue. If I say "The Paris metro was poorly planned," I leave no room for argument. If I add "in my opinion," then it could show that I'm aware that my opinion might not be universal. It could show that I understand the relativist distinction between my experience of the world and yours. It could make my statement harder to attack: If I say "it was poorly planned," you could say "no it wasn't." If I say "I think it was," you certainly can't deny that I think so.
These personal-subjectivity statements are absolutely non-optional when discussing someone else's internal subjective experience. A good psychologist knows you don't say "You're taking this too seriously and are angry," you say "This seems important to you. I can imagine you might feel angry. Is that the case?" We are never in a position to make absolute statements about how someone else feels, and it's foolish to make them even about what they mean. It's wise to say "What I hear you saying is...", in case we're wrong.
But I can think of places in which these subjectivity statements don't help things. For one, they just sound silly when used with true universal absolutes. "In my opinion, the Empire State Building is 1,250 feet tall." Who the heck are you that your opinion is relevant on this matter? (Unless there's some debate about whether the antenna counts...) For a more practical example, when talking to other Stack Exchange users, you might add subjective statements to recommendations about best practices ("As I see it, down-voting isn't useful for new users") and not about explicit policies (you wouldn't say "I feel that questions asking for proofreading are off-topic").
For another, these softening statements are out of place in some contexts that prioritize efficiency or authority, giving orders or instructions. An army officer doesn't need to say "Private, it seems to me that you've assembled that gun incorrectly." A space mission-control engineer doesn't say "In my opinion you should execute a controlled burn for 21 seconds to rotate 10 degrees," they just give the order. These kinds of contexts prioritize clarity and efficiency, and not sensitive and nuanced discussion. (It sounds like the other person in your conversation was suggesting that SE should be this kind of environment... but they're wrong. There is no "mission-critical" urgency to the work that's done here, and more importantly, no "chain of command." It is in fact a community of peers, and needs to be driven by respectful exchange.)
Can these subjectivity statements cause my tone to be misunderstood? Yes, that can be a danger sometimes. First, I should make the disclaimer that "meaning is created by context," and that means that misunderstanding and offense often are too. The person in your quote sounds quite upset, and that was probably caused by more than one statement or phrase. Often when two people in a conversation take offense, they point to specific words or statements—"I can't believe you said that! How dare you say that! No one should ever say that!"—but the real cause for offense is about general feelings and overall mood. In a happy, polite relationship, a single questionable phrase is overlooked, while in a grumpy, suspicious one, the worst intentions are assumed.
That said, and especially if the tone has already become grumpy or suspicious, personal subjectivity statements could backfire. For one thing, they focus on "me." "I think," "I feel," "in my experience," etc. If my tone is already perceived as haughty or bossy, this can just heighten it. In my Empire State Building example, my reaction was "Who are you that I should care about your opinion on its height?" Giving an opinion where it isn't relevant could suggest that you see yourself as some kind of expert or authority. Again, the overall context is probably more to blame here, but it's a reason to avoid over-saturating our communication with these phrases.
It's also best to avoid these subjectivity statements if you don't really mean them. Others have noted that they can do little to soften offensive statements—"In my opinion, you're an idiot" does not become civil by adding "in my opinion." Similarly, adding them to statements that are aggressively assertive or uncompromising can make our apparent civility obviously false. "You claim to have fixed my roof, but I don't feel that you did a good enough job. In my opinion, that's unacceptable. I think you need to come back and do it properly." I'm throwing "I feel" statements into a "here's how it is and what you must do" sentence, and the false politeness could be annoying. Also, I don't actually want to convey some doubt and room for debate in this scenario, and more direct (but still polite) language might help everyone.
So, summary? 1) I would still use them frequently (and do—you can probably find plenty of unconscious examples throughout this answer!). 2) I would ignore advice that calls them "misdirecting equivocating noise," unless I was actually misdirecting and equivocating. As we edit our writing we might find them simply wasting space and diluting our strong thoughts sometimes, but in general they can serve very valuable purposes, and sometimes are absolutely indispensable. 3) I would avoid them in contexts that are truly objective, absolute, and factual, or contexts that prioritize efficiency over diplomacy.

This was one impressively deep and exhaustive answer. You really dived into the topic and quite eloquently touched the different aspects of the original question. I feel reassured now that I used the relativization correctly but I'm glad to have a better insight in what the other user may have reacted to. Awesome! Thank you.

misdirecting equivocating noise, as a description of those phrases ("in my opinion" and the like) could be paraphrased as "something designed to move attention away from the subject at hand" and "not taking a stand one way or another" and "blather", respectively.
That remark is in a caustic style; it has a very high pH.

I share your sensation. However, I want to believe that the person didn't intend any harm. I want to trust that they simply interpreted the addition of in my opinion as provocative and read into it something really bad, hence, only reacting to an act of flawed conduct on my side. So, I wish to investigate if I can make my honest humbleness and benevolent intentions abundantly obvious, even to an irritated recipient. (After all, I can only control my formulation.)

If I understand correctly, the question asked is:

How do I tell someone that I disagree with them, and do it in language that is courteous and respectful?

I've reworded the question because the words in the header don't do justice to the explanation that follows. This is such an important issue, but it's hard to answer fully in this forum which is limited to English language questions. Here are my personal thoughts:

If the quoted paragraph is exactly what you said, it's very hard to understand. This matters when the topic is controversial. You should work hard to make your sentences clear and consistent with what you want people to hear from you.

The three highlighted words felt to me like personal criticism. I think this is because they point to the person as well as the issue being discussed. For example, the word equivocating can refer to a statement, but it also often says something about the person making the statement. It's the kind of word we would use to describe a politician when he doesn't answer an embarrassing question from a reporter.

Therefore, I would focus on the post, not the writer. Continuing the example, I might say: "I don't think that post is relevant to the points I made earlier." You can be clear that you disagree on the issue without saying anything personal about the writer.

Adding in my opinion does not achieve what you want. If your main statement is harsh, it will still be harsh after you've added "in my opinion." You're an idiot (in my opinion).


A well known English phrase is with all due respect. It's often used the way you want: to soften the force of what comes next. I disagree with your views but I still have respect for you as a person. But in movies and TV it's also used ironically to show disrespect. One character says "with all due respect", and the other character interrupts to say, "I doubt that!" This is how I felt when reading your proposed additions.

Sorry for being unclear. The quotation is from their response. I've clarified it now as suggested by Andy. It's verbatim except for a shorter part that I cut out (it was a bit offensive and hardly a contribution to the linguistic dimension of my question here - it's probably more suited for a social skills forum).

And just to clarify. My original statement was that in my opinion there was sufficient information about my technical problem originally (since it got answered) but that others' view may differ. So I added more information to the question, still maintaining that it's superfluous if a reader has sufficient competence.
